How can I identify the spl-token contained within a token account using the token account address?
I am currently sorting through spl-token transfers using the @solana/web3.js library and I need to know the spl token address that is associated with a certain token account to find out which token is being transacted upon.

From you question it seems that you want to fetch the mint from a token account.
You can do that using the getAccount method from the @solana/spl-token library
In code
import { getAccount } from "@solana/spl-token";

// .. add missing imports 

async function getMintFromATA() {
    const tokenAccount = new PublicKey(
        "6SNzQwN2hJBDQnM7bBhYvnHhBg9YJ7Rj6cRLkWhE7nKp"
    ); // ! update me 
    const tokenAccountData = await getAccount(conn, tokenAccount);
    console.log(tokenAccountData);
}
getMintFromATA().then().catch(console.error);

Which would output something similar to this
{
  address: PublicKey [PublicKey(6SNzQwN2hJBDQnM7bBhYvnHhBg9YJ7Rj6cRLkWhE7nKp)] {
    _bn: <BN: 50cad1a2b2ae09cc9352778d68d6195313c936491f3c068bd9f23701b1a38b17>
  },
  mint: PublicKey [PublicKey(BpBqiAoNFYVZr8vr3V5CHFX3HkRwnihNcKnzvxAEZ38e)] {
    _bn: <BN: a0ab6c85eba712b61487cacec200b24dbb3b2082e55ec048d40a8eb9c791ecb3>
  },
  owner: PublicKey [PublicKey(4kg8oh3jdNtn7j2wcS7TrUua31AgbLzDVkBZgTAe44aF)] {
    _bn: <BN: 37c34900bf1a372082b2ec0e9633ee30254fe19c6bce3a1eab456fc51030cf5c>
  },
  amount: 1321102000099994n,
  delegate: null,
  delegatedAmount: 0n,
  isInitialized: true,
  isFrozen: false,
  isNative: false,
  rentExemptReserve: null,
  closeAuthority: null,
  tlvData: <Buffer >
}


Thanks I was able to use the .toBase58() method to extract the mint address.
